# Why doesn't the volume of NH3 = 325 ml in this problem?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, ph, concentration, buffer

I'm struggling with the problem below, and don't understand why

---

> A buffer solution with pH = 9.0 is to be prepared from a 0.2 M ammonia
> solution and a 0.15 M $\ce{HCl}$ solution. The sum of the molar
> concentrations of $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{NH4+}$ in the buffer should be exactly 0.1
> mol/ liter. Calculate the volumes of the two solutions needed to
> prepare 650 ml buffer solution

So I set up my equations and solved, but get a strange result

650 ml = 0.65 liter, $pK_a$($\ce{NH4+}$) = 9.25

c($\ce{NH3}$) + c($\ce{NH4+}$) = 0.1 mol/liter

$\mathrm{pH}$ = $pK_a$ + $\log$(c($\ce{NH3}$) / (0.1 -c($\ce{NH3}$)))

9 = 9.25 + $\log$(c($\ce{NH3}$) / (0.1 - c($\ce{NH3}$)))

Solving this, we get c($\ce{NH3}$) = 0.036 mol/ liter

c($\ce{NH4+}$) = 0.1 - c($\ce{NH3}$) = 0.064 mol/ liter

n($\ce{NH4+}$) = 0.65 liter * 0.064 mol/ liter = 0.0416 mol

The $\ce{HCl}$ will be converted to $\ce{NH4+}$, so n($\ce{NH4+}$) = n($\ce{HCl}$) = 0.0416 mol

v($\ce{HCl}$) = n($\ce{HCl}$) / c($\ce{HCl}$) = 0.0416 mol / 0.15 mol/liter = 0.28 liter

n($\ce{NH3}$) = 0.65 liter * 0.036 mol/liter = 0.0234 mol

Part of the $\ce{NH3}$ will react with $\ce{HCl}$ to form $\ce{NH4+}$, and the rest will remain $\ce{NH3}$

<s>v(NH3) = v(HCl) + n(NH3) / c_initial(NH3) = 0.28 liter + 0.0234 mol / 0.2 mol/liter = 0.397 liter = 397 ml</s>

v($\ce{NH3}$) = (n($\ce{HCl}$) + n($\ce{NH3}$)) / c_initial($\ce{NH3}$) = (0.0416 mol + 0.0234 mol) / 0.2 mol/liter = 0.325 liter = 325 ml

---

Now here is what I don't understand. We start from a concentration of 0.2 M, the sum of the concentration of $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{NH4+}$ should be 0.1 mol/liter, and $\ce{NH3}$ is required to create NH4+. With that in mind, shouldn't the volume of $\ce{NH3}$ be equal to half of the buffer solution, in this case 325 ml ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: *"shouldn't the volume of NH3 be equal to half of the buffer solution, in this case 325 ml?"* - Yes it should, and it seems you were given a terrible question. By the way, the working you show is largely correct until the last four lines, which are meaningless. You aren't adding NH4+ in any way, so the "volume of NH4+" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @orthocresol So it should be v(HCl) instead of v(NH4+) in the last four lines ? What causes the result to be different ? I just noticed that if I multiply n(HCl) / c(HCl) in the fourth last line by 0.15 M / 0.20 M, the rest adds up to 325 ml for NH3, is this a coincidence ?

Comment: If it was just a half of it that would be like a lamest question (yes, I presume there are lamer ones but I don't want to ponder them). For starters concentrations aren't right for that. Another issue is density change in reaction. BTW don't write any "Thanks for your help !" in question - that's not a chat or discussion forum.

Comment: @Mithoron What do you mean ? Why does the density change need to be considered ? I removed the "Thanks for your help !" in question

Comment: @orthocresol What makes you think the question they gave us is terrible (just curious) ?

Comment: I mean, you found the contradiction yourself. A question which asks for a precise number, like this one, should have exactly one answer. It shouldn't have two possible answers depending on which part of it you read first. Nor should it expect you to come up with creative ways around the contradiction such as "adding water", which is not explicitly specified in the question. None of this is good.

Comment: @orthocresol the question is "calculate the volumes of the two solutions needed to *prepare* 650 ml buffer solution".  Very simple.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Regardless of how simple it is, the student's job isn't to play Sherlock Holmes and figure out what the question is missing. Their job is to answer the question.

Comment: @Mithoron Why was this question closed ?

Comment: Why ask me, not the others? Well, I can see issues already in the title - apparently it really is 325, and you claim it's not - false premise, and it's altogether vague and doesn't really describe the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that should have been one of your first equations, leaving you to calculate volume of 0.15 M HCl needed to create the proper amount of NH4Cl in the buffer solution: 280 ml.

What was not asked, but implied, was the balance of 650 ml, 45 ml, would have to be water.